# How to avoid adding duplicate values across nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, duplicates

I have a complex nested dictionary- but I have simplified my issue to this toy example. Adding a value does so across multiple dictionaries and this is not intended:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

Dist_T = defaultdict(lambda:([]))
Filter_T = defaultdict(lambda:Dist_T)
Phase_T = defaultdict(lambda:Filter_T)
    
Phase_T[60]['Green'][4].append('here')
Phase_T[60]['Green'][4].append('there')

Phase_T[60]['Blue'][4].append('over_there') #"over-there" will also be appended to the
                                            # list for the dictionary of the
                                            # Green key which is not intended

print (json.dumps(Phase_T, indent=2))
```

The output is:
`{ "60": { "Green": { "4": [ "here", "there", "over_there" ] }, "Blue": { "4": [ "here", "there", "over_there" ] } } }`

Desired is:
`{ "60": { "Green": { "4": [ "here", "there"] }, "Blue": { "4": [ "over_there" ] } } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare `Phase_T` in one line :

```py
Phase_T = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)))


Phase_T[60]['Green'][4].append('here')
Phase_T[60]['Green'][4].append('there')

Phase_T[60]['Blue'][4].append('over_there')

print (json.dumps(Phase_T, indent=2))
```

This prints :

```
{
  "60": {
    "Green": {
      "4": [
        "here",
        "there"
      ]
    },
    "Blue": {
      "4": [
        "over_there"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Come on! That is subtle.THANK YOU! I do not understand why this would matter- I have wasted quite a few hours on this.